# Selecting a price from a datelist based on an order date

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a table with Costprices and a table with orderlines

CostPrices table:

```
Price_id, product_id, date, price
1,24,2018-08-06,100
2,24,2019-01-01,80
3,56,2018-11-11,500
4,57,2018-07-10,400
5,58,2017-01-01,500
```

orderlines table:

```
order_id, product_id, date, customer_id, qty, sales_price
1, 24, 2018-08-10, 344, 10, 250
2, 24, 2018-11-11, 538, 5, 250
3, 24, 2019-06-06, 678, 100, 250
```

I need to select the active costprice at the date of the orderline. like:

```
select
    ol.order_id,
    ol.product_id,
    ol.date,
    ol.customer_id,
    ol.qty,
    ----costprice @ orderdate ---,
    ol.sales_price

from orderlines as ol

left outer join Costprices as cp on cp.product_id = ol.product_id
```

I have been searching on how to do this and usually get to using a calculated maxdate, this is great for getting the last prices, but not when you do not need the last one, but one earlier at a specific date.

I have a feeling it might be very easy, but can't get my head around

I am using Postgres SQL 10 trying to write sql queries in tableplus

```
select
ol.order_id,
ol.product_id,
ol.date`
ol.customer_id,
ol.qty,
----costprice @ orderdate ---,
ol.sales_price

from orderlines as ol

let outer join Costprices as cp on cp.product_id = ol.product_id
```

I am expecting

```
order_id, product_id, date, customer_id, qty, Costprice ,sales_price
1, 24, 2018-08-10, 344, 10, 100, 250
2, 24, 2018-11-11, 538, 5, 100, 250
3, 24, 2019-06-06, 678, 100, 80, 250
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select ol.*, cp.costprice
from orderlines ol left join lateral
     (select cp.*
      from costprices cp
      where cp.product_id = ol.product_id and
            cp.date <= ol.date
      order by cp.date desc
      limit 1
     ) cp
     on 1=1;
```

In your case, you can also use a correlated subquery.  Basically, you just move `cp` into the `select` clause, if you prefer that method.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will have a go.. never thought about sorting and limiting the returned field by just one...still learning and very grateful for the help.